# Generating function containing Incomplete gamma function

Tags: analysis, generating-functions, closed-form, gamma-function

Consider the following generating function  :

$$\sum_{k=0}^\infty\sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{m=0}^\infty \frac {n^{2m+4}(-1)^m\Gamma(2k+1,-(am+b))}{m!(am+b)^{2k+1}} x^{2k}$$

Where , $\Gamma(p,q)$ is incomplete gamma function

$a,b,$ are constants .

> > Question :How to get a closed form of this generating function  ?